# Subdivision respecting adjacent edges

Tags: mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have this set of meshes that i use to generate my levels with.
Now, I have used a subdivision script in runtime with unity, but that is quite heavy.

I was thinking about doing the subdivision in Blender, but if I do it per mesh, the final mesh will end up looking full of holes.

Is there anyway I can subdivide the meshes here, keeping the corners of the mesh where they are?

[image: strong text]

Answer (score 2):

You can mark edge creases to control the subdivision's interpolation: select an edge, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, then drag your mouse and left-click to confirm.

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Subdividing will always cause this issue. For a smooth look, you can right-click on the mesh and then select shade smooth. If you want a few areas to be smooth or rounded, you can go to edit mode and select the edge you want to smooth, then use the bevel option, the option below:

[image]

pull the yellow line on it, and keep pulling to the extent you want to smooth. Then go to the bottom left, of the viewport. You will see an option that says bevel and a triangle near it. Click on the triangle and set segments and set it to 10, in this section :

[image]

Then, you will get a rounded edge. This is better than subdividing it. Subdividing always makes stuff with sharp points look worse and unity would never accept a heavily subdivided model.

Hope my answer helps.